# Why won't text fields respond to hiding the keyboard?

Tags: xcode, resignfirstresponder

This is my code:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField  {
    [txtSiteDesc resignFirstResponder];
    [txtDesc resignFirstResponder];
    [ssFS resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
```

}

This is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface slEnterDataViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>  {

    UITextField *txtSiteDesc;
    UITextField *txtDesc;
    UITextField *ssFS;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtSiteDesc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtDesc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *ssFS;

@end
```

It works for the txtSiteDesc, but not any of the others.  I assume the problem is in the textFieldShouldReturn method;  I thought I could check the value of "textField" to see which field it is and then execute the appropriate "resignFirstResponder" and return.  I'm close (I think) but not close enough.

Help would be greatly appreciated. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you've set the delegate for `txtSiteDesc` but not for your other two text fields?  This would explain why `textFieldShouldReturn:` is called for your first text field not not the others.  Make sure you are setting the `delegate` property of all three textfields to `self` (where self = your view controller).

Comment: Thank you so much... works like a champ now!  I appreciate your help... :D

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this problem. This is what you are looking for :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([string hasSuffix:@"\n"])
    {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This will hide the keyboard when you press return/done etc. on the keyboard.